# Rest API User Levels

Tags: functions, api, rest-api

I've got a a mobile angularjs app that's using https://github.com/Tmeister/wp-api-jwt-auth jwt auth to add to WP_Rest API www.wp-api.org which works fine, when a user is an Administrator. However, when an editor tries to login I get the error;

```
code
:
"rest_user_cannot_view"
data
:
{status: 401}
message
:
"Sorry, you cannot view this resource."
```

I can't work out how to change the user levels anywhere:

```
   createAccessToken:function(user){
                    var token = '';
                    $http.post( serviceBase + 'wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token', {
                        username: user.username,
                        password: user.password
                    } )
                    .then( function( response ) {
                        console.log(response.data);   
                        token = response.data.token;
                        Token.set(token);
                    } )
                    .catch( function( error ) {
                        console.error( 'Error', error.data[0] );
                    } );

                    return token;
                },
```

Comment: Have you opened an issue with the author/support?

Comment: It's not active on github, no ones questions have been answered really, i wondered if it was just something stupid I was missing